# Does anyone know the IR Pattern integer for Daikin air conditioner (I want to simulate on/off signal)

Tags: java, android, infrared, remote-control, transmitfile

I was trying to build an android app to act like air conditioner remote control that can turn on and off my Daikin AC. Does anyone know where I can find the IR pattern code? I've done my research on internet for a whole day but I can't find any useful database with my AC model

My remote control model is ARC480A23

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Context context = requireContext().getApplicationContext();
        ip_textview = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_first);
        Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Signal received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        ConsumerIrManager ir_service = (ConsumerIrManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE);

        int[] pattern = {/*this will be filled with IR pattern code*/};

        binding.buttonFirst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                v.vibrate(500);
                ir_service.transmit(38000, pattern);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I eventually use arduino to get the IR patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decoded the remote with Arduino using IR receiver. The pattern was so long that it couldn't decoded with <IRRemote.h> library. I have to decode the remote without any arduino libraries.

Here are the patterns:

```
int[] patternOFF = {204, 49272, 208, 444, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 25288, 3400, 1816, 360, 1376, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 1380, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 1380, 356, 512, 360, 1376, 360, 1380, 360, 512, 356, 1380, 360, 1380, 360, 1380, 360, 1380, 356, 1380, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 1352, 384, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 364, 504, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 508, 364, 508, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 508, 364, 508, 360, 508, 360, 508, 360, 1380, 360, 1380, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 1380, 360, 1376, 360, 512, 356, 1384, 356, 1384, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 1380, 360, 1376, 360, 1380, 360, 1380, 360, 508, 360, 1356, 388, 504, 360, 1380, 360, 508, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 512, 412, 456, 360, 508, 360, 512, 412, 456, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 1380, 364, 504, 360, 1380, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 1380, 360, 1380, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 1376, 360, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 1380, 360, 508, 360, 508, 360, 512, 356, 512, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 1380, 356, 512, 360, 1380, 356, 1380, 360, 508, 360, 512, 360, 49944, 84};
        

int[] patternON = {460, 404, 464, 404, 464, 408, 464, 404, 464, 368, 500, 25188, 3500, 1720, 456, 1280, 456, 412, 456, 412, 464, 404, 436, 1308, 432, 424, 468, 412, 460, 412, 432, 440, 456, 1284, 452, 412, 456, 1284, 456, 1284, 456, 412, 432, 1308, 432, 1308, 456, 1280, 460, 1280, 456, 1284, 456, 408, 460, 412, 460, 1284, 452, 412, 460, 408, 464, 408, 456, 412, 460, 412, 456, 412, 460, 412, 456, 408, 460, 412, 460, 408, 460, 412, 460, 408, 460, 408, 460, 412, 460, 408, 460, 412, 456, 412, 484, 368, 472, 1288, 456, 408, 460, 412, 460, 412, 452, 1284, 460, 1280, 456, 416, 456, 408, 460, 408, 460, 412, 456, 1288, 452, 412, 456, 1284, 456, 1284, 456, 416, 452, 416, 456, 412, 456, 412, 456, 416, 456, 408, 460, 416, 452, 416, 452, 416, 456, 412, 456, 1284, 456, 1284, 456, 1284, 456, 1284, 452, 416, 456, 1284, 452, 416, 456, 1284, 452, 416, 456, 412, 456, 416, 452, 416, 452, 420, 452, 416, 452, 416, 452, 420, 452, 416, 452, 420, 448, 420, 452, 416, 452, 420, 452, 416, 452, 416, 452, 420, 452, 416, 452, 416, 452, 420, 452, 416, 452, 440, 428, 420, 448, 424, 448, 420, 452, 440, 424, 420, 452, 420, 448, 444, 424, 424, 448, 444, 424, 444, 424, 444, 428, 444, 424, 444, 428, 440, 428, 444, 424, 444, 424, 448, 424, 444, 424, 444, 424, 448, 420, 448, 424, 448, 420, 448, 420, 448, 420, 452, 420, 448, 420, 452, 416, 1320, 420, 452, 416, 1324, 416, 452, 416, 452, 416, 452, 420, 1320, 420, 1320, 416, 452, 420, 452, 416, 452, 416, 452, 420, 452, 416, 452, 416, 452, 420, 452, 416, 452, 420, 452, 416, 452, 416, 1324, 416, 452, 416, 452, 420, 452, 392, 476, 416, 1324, 416, 1320, 420, 452, 416, 452, 420, 1320, 416, 1324, 416, 1320, 420, 1320, 416};
      

int[] patternCANCEL = {328, 536, 332, 540, 332, 536, 332, 540, 328, 540, 332, 25316, 3376, 1840, 332, 1408, 328, 540, 328, 540, 332, 536, 336, 1408, 328, 540, 332, 536, 332, 536, 332, 540, 332, 1404, 332, 536, 336, 1408, 332, 1408, 328, 540, 332, 1408, 328, 1408, 332, 1408, 332, 1404, 332, 1408, 332, 536, 336, 536, 332, 1408, 328, 540, 332, 536, 332, 540, 332, 536, 332, 536, 336, 532, 336, 536, 332, 536, 332, 536, 332, 540, 332, 536, 332, 536, 336, 536, 332, 536, 332, 536, 336, 536, 332, 536, 336, 536, 332, 1408, 332, 536, 332, 536, 332, 536, 336, 1404, 336, 1404, 332, 536, 336, 536, 332, 536, 336, 1404, 332, 1408, 332, 1404, 332, 536, 336, 1404, 336, 536, 332, 536, 332, 536, 336, 536, 332, 536, 332, 536, 336, 536, 332, 536, 332, 540, 332, 536, 332, 1408, 332, 1404, 336, 1404, 332, 1404, 336, 536, 332, 1404, 336, 536, 332, 1408, 332, 536, 336, 532, 336, 532, 336, 536, 332, 536, 336, 536, 332, 536, 336, 536, 332, 536, 332, 536, 336, 532, 336, 536, 332, 536, 336, 508, 360, 536, 336, 532, 336, 536, 332, 536, 336, 532, 336, 536, 332, 536, 336, 532, 336, 536, 336, 532, 336, 508, 360, 512, 360, 532, 336, 536, 332, 536, 336, 504, 364, 536, 332, 536, 336, 532, 336, 536, 332, 536, 336, 532, 336, 508, 364, 532, 336, 508, 364, 504, 364, 508, 360, 508, 360, 508, 364, 508, 360, 508, 364, 532, 336, 508, 360, 536, 336, 1404, 336, 532, 336, 1404, 332, 512, 360, 508, 360, 508, 364, 1404, 332, 1404, 336, 504, 364, 508, 364, 504, 364, 508, 364, 1400, 336, 508, 364, 504, 364, 508, 360, 508, 364, 504, 364, 508, 364, 1400, 336, 508, 364, 504, 364, 508, 360, 508, 360, 1404, 336, 508, 360, 1380, 360, 1384, 356, 1404, 336, 1376, 360, 1380, 360, 1376, 364, 43080, 84};
    

int[] patternPOWERFUL = {524, 372, 468, 400, 468, 400, 440, 432, 440, 428, 440, 25180, 3572, 1648, 528, 1236, 500, 368, 504, 364, 504, 368, 500, 1240, 500, 368, 504, 364, 504, 364, 504, 368, 504, 1232, 504, 368, 500, 1240, 500, 1236, 504, 368, 500, 1240, 500, 1236, 504, 1236, 500, 1240, 500, 1236, 504, 364, 508, 364, 504, 1208, 528, 368, 504, 364, 504, 368, 500, 368, 496, 372, 468, 404, 412, 456, 412, 456, 432, 440, 456, 412, 488, 380, 496, 376, 464, 404, 436, 432, 464, 404, 464, 360, 508, 356, 512, 304, 564, 1280, 464, 380, 484, 384, 484, 384, 488, 1276, 464, 1272, 464, 384, 484, 388, 480, 388, 484, 384, 484, 1276, 464, 388, 480, 388, 484, 1276, 464, 384, 484, 384, 484, 388, 480, 388, 484, 384, 484, 388, 488, 380, 484, 384, 488, 360, 508, 360, 508, 1276, 464, 1276, 460, 1276, 464, 1276, 464, 356, 516, 1272, 464, 360, 512, 1272, 464, 364, 508, 356, 512, 356, 516, 352, 516, 356, 512, 356, 516, 356, 512, 356, 516, 348, 520, 356, 516, 356, 512, 360, 512, 296, 572, 360, 508, 312, 556, 408, 460, 408, 460, 412, 436, 432, 440, 432, 436, 432, 440, 432, 492, 376, 520, 348, 528, 344, 524, 344, 524, 348, 516, 352, 484, 384, 484, 384, 456, 416, 428, 440, 412, 1328, 412, 456, 412, 460, 412, 456, 436, 432, 440, 432, 464, 404, 464, 404, 468, 404, 464, 404, 468, 400, 468, 404, 464, 404, 464, 380, 488, 384, 484, 384, 484, 1252, 484, 388, 456, 1280, 460, 412, 456, 412, 456, 412, 460, 1284, 452, 1284, 456, 412, 456, 412, 456, 416, 452, 416, 456, 416, 452, 416, 452, 416, 456, 416, 452, 416, 456, 416, 452, 416, 452, 1308, 428, 444, 428, 440, 428, 444, 424, 444, 428, 440, 428, 444, 424, 1316, 424, 444, 424, 444, 424, 1316, 424, 1316, 420, 1320, 416};

int carrierFrequency = 38000; //38kHz remote frequency
```